# Count all values of the last 60 minutes

Tags: android, sqlite, date, timestamp, android-sqlite

I am currently working on a Project, where an Android App is saving some values with a timestamp in a SQLite Database. The timestamp is stored as type "DATE NOT NULL" in the format "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss". 
(for example: ID: 1 | Timestamp: 2017-11-19  21:05:04 | Value: 1234).

Now, for some calculations, i have to choose the number of entries, which where created/stored in the last 60 minutes since the current time.

So i need something like:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM TableName WHERE Timestamp > current_timestamp - 60 Minutes
```

Can you help me? One Problem is, that i cant change the way the Timestamp is saved.

I searched many topics which seem to be similar, but can't get it to work.

Thanks for reading and helping.
cold1ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored timestamp seems legit for sqlite processing.

Just to be on the safe side you can try applying datetime() to it  when using it in date calculations.

As regards your question, you have to do it approximately thus:

```
WHERE datetime(timestamp) > datetime(current_timestamp, '-60 minutes')
```

Comment: That seems to work in some way. i will test it for robustness and give feedback. thank you gnudiff!

Comment: This works very good. Only thing is, that my current timestamp is 1 hour wrong due to time-shift. But i fixed it by subtracting another 60 minutes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @cold1ce no problem. Regarding times, sqlite stores and expects times in GMT always. If your table values are (as they could well be) in your local TZ, you could also try datetime(timestamp, '-60 minutes', 'localtime')